# Yii2 yiisoft/yii2-authclient sometimes login problem in mobile

Tags: php, yii2

I setup google login with Yii2 "yiisoft/yii2-authclient", Everthing works fine in my desktop. (login & logout)

But when i try to login from mobile sometimes it shows error for me but sometimes work.
I'm really confused why its happening like magic.

I used :

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient

My code :

**SiteController.php**

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout','signup','createad','upload','remove'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['signup','auth'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout','createad','upload','remove','update-leads','select-category','send-mail','logout-mobile'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                    'logout-mobile'=>['get']
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'auth' => [
                'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
                'successCallback' => [$this, 'onAuthSuccess'],
            ],
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Error in mobile (When login using google) :

```
Bad Request (#400)

Invalid auth state parameter.

The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.

Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.
```

I can't understand why its work in desktop but not in mobile (Google chrome)
Same browser i used in desktop but it works perfectly.

I tried in Mozilla Firefox from my mobile works perfect like desktop. Also i checked for chrome mobile update but its up to date.

Anyone can help me what is wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: First look at application.log and nginx/apache logs maybe there you can find more information about your error.

Comment: How i can find the logs, i have access to cpanel and whm.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser on the mobile?

Comment: yes. in mozilla firefox it works fine. chrome has issue.